# How do I stop the navbar from disappearing when I click the back button on iOS using Ionic 2?

Tags: ios, angular, animation, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm creating a simple Ionic starter and I'm having some issues with the navbar. Whenever I access a list item and go back to the list, the navbar disappears during the animation. This only happens on iOS as the animation is different on Android. You can see the animation in the GIF below.

I'm using ionic-angular 3.0.1 and Angular 4.0.0.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue. I used the class 'header' to set the background. This class is shared on iOS in navbar, which caused it to change during the animation.